# delete notification from list view and notification bar at the same time

Tags: android

I want to delete notification and at the same time notification should be deleted from list view. and if I delete notification from listview it should be deleted from notification bar. what to do.

Comment: First, please structure your question better and state what have you tried already.

Comment: Notification has it's own ID. Delete it by ID

Comment: how to find selected notification's id.

Answer (score 0):

First, please structure your question better and state what have you tried already.

To answer your question, clearing both, you would need to keep a record of all `Notification` IDs (and tags) that you used with `NotificationManager`.

- When you delete an item in your `ListView`, invoke [`NotificationManager`'s `cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) method. This will cancel a notification matching the specified ID (and tag).
- When creating a `Notification`, provide a separate `PendingIntent` for the the "delete" or "clear" action by using [`Notification.Builder`'s `setDeleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)), providing a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for it and clear the appropriate item in your `ListView`.

Comment: I have generated multiple notifications with unique id so I want to get the particular notification's id... what to do?

Comment: you create a mapping between your notification id and your item id in your list. you can also pass additional reference within the delete PendingIntent.